# Swing problem with InputMap/ActionMap

Tags: java, swing

I want my JTextField to process the text not only when ENTER is pressed,
but also when SPACE is pressed.  You can see in the code below that I associated the action that is usually associated with ENTER to SPACE, but I get some unexpected behavior (see below).

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textField;

    public Test() {
        textField = new JTextField();
        add(textField);
        InputMap inputMap = this.textField.getInputMap();
        Object actionSubmit = inputMap.get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"));
        Object actionSubmitSp = inputMap.get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"));
        System.out.println("actionSubmit for space = " + actionSubmitSp);
        ActionMap actionMap = this.textField.getActionMap();
        Action action = actionMap.get(actionSubmit);
        System.out.println("actionSubmit = " + actionSubmit);
        textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"),
                actionSubmit);

        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                textField.setText(null);
                System.out.println("event received:[" + 
                        evt.getActionCommand() + "]");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Test test = new Test();
                test.pack();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I type "x SPACE" an ActionEvent is produced and the JTextField is cleared. 
However the refreshed JTextField
is not a "null" string as requested,  but " ".  The SPACE from the previous action 
has "leaked" to the refreshed JTextField, which is quite annoying.

I looked in the swing code a bit.  My best guess is that an ActionEvent is generated from some KeyEvent's, and KeyEvent.isConsumed() has different consequences depending if the KeyEvent was a ENTER or a SPACE (an ENTER is swallowed, but not a SPACE).

Anyone knows how to fix this? Or knows a different method to accomplish my goal?

Comment: You can keep all the code in the ActionListener. See below.

Comment: For my use case the action listener for SPACE key is not triggered at all (though the syntax seems just fine)... Maybe it is because SPACE key has a special meaning for OS and Java (action key for focused element)? Btw the key listener for SPACE does not work there too for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple events are being generated. Your code is being executed on a `keyPressed` event. However using the space bar also results in a `keyTyped` event being generated. This is handled by the text component after the `keyPressed` code has been executed, so the `Document` is cleared and then a space is added to it.

> Anyone knows how to fix this?

Don't use a `KeyListener`.

Add your code to the end of the EDT so that is executes AFTER the `Document` has been updated with the space:

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent evt)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                textField.setText(null);
                System.out.println("event received:[" + evt.getActionCommand() + "]");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution too, but I think the KeyListener is a cleaner/more readable solution.

Comment: @toto, Having code in one place is a cleaner / more readable and easier to maintain. Also, in general, KeyListeners should be avoided. Swing was designed to use Key Bindings. You are attempting to mix bindings and event listeners which is more confusing.

Comment: @camickr Can you please link to some supporting documentation to your comments regarding KeyListeners and KeyBindings?  I'm just curious as to where you heard this.  (BTW I think both solutions are just fine.)

Comment: @Joshua, there is no one thing to read. Its an accumulation of programming knowledge over time. In general, higher level abstractions should be used. Swing is more evolved than AWT and provides these abstractions. For some basics you can read up on [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). The solutions are NOT the same. It does NOT make sense to use both an ActionListener and a KeyListener to accomplish one piece of functionality. This is a maintenance nightmare. Again experience is your guide.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I never said the solutions are the same.  Now enough of this and on to answering the next questions! :)

Answer (score 3):

I adapted your test case to use a key listener to consume the space character when it was typed.  Just add the following and leave the rest as is.

```
    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == ' ') {
                System.out.println("Was a space character");
                e.consume();
            }
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

I believe the issue is that ENTER isn't a displayable character for the text field while the space character is.  If you tried something similar like this with a text area my guess is that you would encounter the same problem with the ENTER key as well.

Comment: Thanks!  It can be made shorter with KeyAdapter instead of KeyListener (no need to define keyPressed and keyReleased).

Comment: -1 for continuing to do things the wrong way despite the proper way having been explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: @BradMace If you look at the time stamps you will see that I posted my answer before the accepted and completely correct answer.  I left this here so others would see my mistake.  If I wasn't clear enough before, I completely agree with the accepted answer.  Go ahead and give me a down vote if you like but your statement is incorrect with respect to when my answer was posted.